# IBM Watson NLU: extract entities sentiment

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-nlu

I'm working with Watson NLU (with a custom model) and my problem is that when I ask for the entities sentiment (as explained in the documentation) the POST doesn't return it, just the entity type. I pass this features:

```
    "features": {   
            "sentiment": {}, 
            "relations":{
                "model":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
            },
            "entities":{
                 "model":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
                 "sentiment":"1" ----I've tried with "true" too---
            }
     }
```

¿Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Custom model overrides the normal model. Does the same happen if you don't use a custom model?

Comment: I can't restore the default model to try it, I've tried to undeploy my custom one but it seems that it's not getting the entities...

Comment: When you make your call, you specify your model. If you don't specify one, it should take the default. You don't need to uninstall your model.

Comment: Other thing to check is to set the language attribute so that it doesn't try to guess.

Comment: I've done both, undeploy and not specifying the model id, but now any entities are found. And when I try with my model I always specify the language

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable targeted sentiment for entities, you need to set `"sentiment": true`.  Note that you don't need quotes around true, it is a boolean value not a string.  See below

`"features": {
    "sentiment": {}, 
    "relations":{
        "model":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    },
    "entities":{
        "model":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "sentiment": true
    }
}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't work... The result is exactly the same as before, for each entity I receive: 

 {
            "type": "MODIFIER",
            "text": "special",
            "disambiguation": {
                "subtype": [
                    "NONE"
                ]
            },
            "count": 1
        }